# How would I turn a list of strings into a proper list

Tags: python, string, list

I am writing a program and I would just like to know how to turn this:

```
['(', '1', '1', '1', ')']
```

Into this:

```
[(1,1,1)]
```

Comment: this should give you the desired result `[tuple(map(int, my_list[1:-1]))]`

Comment: you mean a list with one single element: a tuple

Comment: Is there any chance we can convince you not to even try and instead fix the code that gives you those strings? This question is like asking "I have this gun that really hurts when I shoot myself in the foot with it, is there any way I can make the bullets less painful?". The correct solution is to not shoot yourself in the foot in the first place.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I have to shoot my foot

Comment: @Aran-Fey I am actually writing the list to a file, and then reading it into a file

Comment: @Slipknot1 Then don't do that. Save it to a file in some format that's made for this—e.g., use `json.dump` to save it, then `json.load` to load it back.

Comment: From your comment on the answer, you're converting each line into a list of single-character strings. Whether you're doing that at writing time or at reading time, that's making things even _harder_. And it will completely break if you've got, say, a 2-digit number in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `ast.literal_eval` and list indexing / slicing.

```
from ast import literal_eval

lst = ['(', '1', '1', '1', ')']

res = [literal_eval(lst[0] + ','.join(lst[1:-1]) + lst[-1])]

# [(1, 1, 1)]
```

But, as already mentioned, try and resolve this upstream first.

With updated data:

```
lst = ['(', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ')']

res = list(literal_eval(''.join(lst)))

# [((1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)),
#  ((1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1))]
```

Comment: It might be simpler and cleaner to just map `literal_eval` over `lst[1:-1]` instead of joining them up into a tuple to eval.

Comment: @abarnert, Fair point. But I am wary of the fact not all the elements in the OP's dataset may be tuples. Some may be `set`, `list`, etc. Need some more information about how the data got into that state in the first place.

Comment: @jpp Here is the full file ['(', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ',', ' ', '(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')', ')']

Comment: But your code is building a tuple display to eval, which is at least as brittle to such things as building a tuple out of a map over eval.

Comment: @Slipknot1 Is that actually what's in the file, or is that what you get when you do something like `for line in file: print(list(line))`?

Comment: @abarnert that is the actual file

Comment: @Slipknot1 Then you didn't just write the list to a file, you converted the list to a string, then converted that string into a list of characters, then wrote _that_ to the file. So you're not just shooting yourself in the foot, you're nuking yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the result :

```
data=['(', '1', '1', '1', ')']

print([tuple(map(int,filter(lambda x:x.isdigit(),data)))])
```

output:

```
[(1, 1, 1)]
```